# IP.Board reply on another forum

Tags: ipb

I am wondering if anyone knows the information on how to make automatic replies to threads that us the IP.Board forum. I'm not planning to write a spam bot however there is a forum when people are for x service, and our app can automatically detect if they are looking for what we offer and are hoping to have it automatically reply with some information.

If someone knows how, or has a link to the documention - that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you want to post a reply to an IP.Board forum run by somebody else?  Or this your own forum you are posting to?  Can you explain what you are trying to do a bit more?  Also, can you show us what you've found that didn't help?

Comment: Please take the time to read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to their docs](http://www.invisionpower.com/support/guides/_/advanced-and-developers/api-methods/xml-rpc-api-r62), you can use the `postReply` call:

> postReply
>
> - member_field: This should be the field to look up the 'member_key' in (for instance, 'member_id', 'email', 'members_display_name', etc.)
> - member_key: The value to search in 'member_field' with in order to find the poster. You may pass member_field as ID and member_key as 1,
>     for instance, to post a reply as member ID 1.
> - topic_id: The ID of the topic to post the reply in
> - post_content: The contents of the first post

If that isn't working, probably the administrator has turned off XML-RPC out of safety.